# Java: Is the line args[0].length possible?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I am wondering if the java line `if (args[0].length > 2)` is a valid line. I'm taking in command-line arguments, and I want to find out if the amount of numbers in the first array is longer than two digits. For example, the year 2014 would allow the `if` statement to be true. If the user's input was for example 52 then the `if` statement wouldn't be true and it'd move onto an `else if` statement below.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it? If yes, why do you even ask? If no, why not?

Comment: `args[0].length` --> no, `args[0]` is not an array; `args[0].length()` --> yes, since `args[0]` is a `String` and `String` has a `.length()` method.

Answer (score 5):

It's a valid line *if* `args` is declared as a `String[][]` - but that wouldn't be how a `main` method would be declared. `length` is a valid member of an *array*, but it's not a (public) member of the `String` class.

If you're trying to check the length of a string, you want the `length()` *method* instead. For example:

```
if (args[0].length() > 2)
```

You might want to first check that there *are* some arguments, using `args.length`. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("You need to give me an argument!");
        return;
    }
    if (args[0].length() > 2) {
        System.out.println("The first argument has more than 2 characters");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The first argument has 0-2 characters");
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd `System.exit(2);` in the case of a missing argument case to indicate an error ;) (edit: not `1` since the JVM returns 1 in the event of an uncaught exception by `main()`

Comment: @fge: I *might* do that as well (although I'd probably use 1 ;) but I didn't want to complicate things more than necessary. I'd probably write to stderr, too...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with `String#length()` method and also I think `null` check should be added

```
if (args[0]!=null && args[0].length() > 2)
```

Comment: If this is a `main` method, `args` won't be `null` -- so the null check is just noise.

Answer (score 0):

If `args[0]` is an array and is not `null` then

```
if (args[0].length > 2)
```

is a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (args[0].length > 2)
```

Its `invalid` expression bcoz String don't contain any length field.

Change to

`if (args[0].length() > 2)` to get the length of the String

Comment: Does `String` has a `length` field? I know of a `length()` method.

Comment: ohh sry typo mistake,string only contain length method

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about command line arguments, so...

> I was wondering if the java line "if (args[0].length > 2)" is a valid line.

No. `args` is a `String[]`, therefore `args[0]` is a `String`. And a `String` does not have a `length` public static field.

However:

> I want to find out if the amount of numbers in the first array is longer than two digits

So, as mentioned, `args[0]` is a `String`. **It is not an array!**. Unlike C, for instance, there is no "direct mapping" of a `String` to a `char[]`. In fact, C has nothing like `String`. With Java, you'd have to use `.toCharArray()` to get a `char[]` from a `String`.

If you want to find if a `String` has more than two numbers, then you should write:

```
if (args[0].matches("[0-9]{2,}"))
```

This will check both that the string is 2 characters long or more, and that all characters in it are digits.

This uses a [regular expression](http://regex.info) to check your argument. If the regex succeeds, you can then convert to an integer using:

```
Integer.parseInt(args[0])
```

provided there is no overflow!